Why does the gstreamer "play a section of a media file" example block?
I'm in the process of learning how to build an application in C using gstreamer, and I'm working my way through examples.  In particular, I'm having an issue with the play a section of a media file example on the "Pipeline manipulation" section.
Under Ubuntu 24.04, it builds just fine, and runs - but nothing is ever played.  I added some code to the cb_message() callback to see what other messages it's getting - and there are some GST_MESSAGE_BUFFERING messages after setting the pipeline to GST_STATE_PLAYING. I added some debug output there, and it does eventually get to 100% - but still nothing plays, even if I add a call to gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING) there.  In case it matters, the URI I've been using is the same one used in other tutorials on the gstreamer site: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm
So... seems like maybe this example needs updating.  Any suggestions?  It's kind of frustrating when trying to learn something if the examples don't work.  :) :) :)
EDIT: looks like it's only meant to be used with a local file, not a stream?  The same file works fine locally.  I'd love to know why this is the case, and if it's possible to play a section of a file retrieved over the network...

I think the example is meant to be used with a file, not a stream.

*facepalm* - sure enough, if I copy it locally and use a file:/// URI, it works as expected.  Thanks for the answer - I'm trying to mark it as such.

As Florian Zwoch commented - this example only works with a local file, not a stream.  The same file works fine if retrieved then played via a file:/// URI.
